# A carbon fracture or a paint crack?

Tags: carbon, crack

I’ve spotted this crack on my carbon fork, only on the left side. The crack is exactly at the joint of aluminum dropout and carbon body of the fork. My bike is a 2010 Trek Madone Project One (OCLV carbon) and the fork is Bontrager RXL. Yesterday I’ve sent an enquiry to Trek via my bike shop, waiting for their response.

I am curious if there is anybody who experienced anything similar? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try tapping with a coin.  If the sound changes and becomes dull around the cracked paint, the underlying structure is cracked.  See https://www.google.com/search?q=carbon+fiber+tap+test

Comment: Almost certainly a paint crack.

Comment: @Daniel Hicks Pretty bold statement when that crack in the paint appears "at the joint of aluminum dropout and carbon body of the fork."

Comment: Though cracked paint is likliest to occur at a joint.  Of 2 different materials

Comment: You'll get as many answers as there are replies.  The only answer you should trust is from the manufacturer and from your LBS who has seen it in person.  And even then they could be wrong.    Aside - good work spotting the crack.

Comment: Stop using it at once and have it examined. If any doubt remains, have it replaced. This is potentially lethal.

Comment: Only way to be sure is to sand the paint off or get it xrayed.  However zooming in, it looks like the 'R' has some impact damage, so i'm leaning towards it being structural damage.

Comment: 'Survey' type questions  - asking if anyone has experienced something similar - don't work well on this site as they don't have objective answers. The best we can do here is tell you that crack is cause for concern and to contact the manufacturer, which you have already done.

Comment: Am I seeing right? There is a horizontal fault-line that stops close to the front edge and from there a very thin line goes down at a right angle?

Comment: Actually, the real problem is that that bike is too clean!!

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, I've contacted Trek and waiting for the outcome of their assessment. Will let you know once have a solution.

Comment: My 2011 Madone is cracked 75% around one fork and 50% around the other I discovered today. I little lower than the one pictured.

Comment: @KürşadTerzi What was the result? It would be great to know.

Comment: if you think it's worth it, get an NDT guy to scan it.

Comment: fork damage is no joke, they are cheap to replace, just get a new one

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a carbon crack.  Either way, do not even ride it down the driveway.
The awesome news is that trek warrants that and you can expect a replacement.

Comment: Reading through the Trek warranties is a bit hit and miss, I can only find info for 2018-2020 bikes, nothing is mentioned about 2010 models and if your a subsequent owner your warranty is only 3 years and not lifetime